# Как реализовать правильно график heatmap (highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Немного переделал график из примера, таким образом - http://jsfiddle.net/52dst6fy/

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
    },

    xAxis: {

        "type": "datetime",
        "minTickInterval": 86400000

    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#000000',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: 'rgb(41, 182, 246)',
        data: [[1444534400000, 3, 5], [1442534400000, 3, 5], [1444534400000, 2, 200]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]

});
```

});

Дело в том, что пропали цвета, нарастающие за счет увеличения данных (3я цифра, первое это время, 2я определяет день недели).
Пытаюсь реализовать графки, похожий на это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неправильно идут данные, первая значение - положение y, второе - положение x, третье - значение точки

```
data: [[1, 3, 1244534400], [2, 2, 1042534400], [3, 1, 444500000]],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/startsevdenis/52dst6fy/1/

UPD:

Нужно немного подготовить данные

http://jsfiddle.net/startsevdenis/52dst6fy/2/

Comment: Спасибо! Но суть в том, что первая цифра, например 1444534400000, это время (Date.UTC), то есть по сути требуется, что бы нижняя положение, было время в часах.

Comment: То есть вы хотите чтобы по оси x шли часы?

Comment: Да, все верно, в часах

Comment: есть решение какое-нибудь?

Comment: Есть, обновил ответ

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое, то что нужно, еще вопрос, есть ли возможность сделать меньше по ширине боксы? http://i.imgur.com/51NUrD7.png    UPD: вопрос решен